# Redesign grid-layout without table-tags

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm reworking an existing module to make it more adaptive. Below is a general mock-up of the current design. This design is used for multiple things, and the goal is that adding or removing modules should be easy.

Right now, we're using a HTML `<table>` to achieve the lay-out, using `col-span` and `row-span` everywhere, but that becomes very messy, very fast (especially if we want to remove a module, or add another module of a different size).

What would a proper way to work around this, be? I'm not looking after a full solution, I'd rather have a small example that I can extend on.

I tried Bootstrap, but some of the modules have fixed sizes, which messes up the GRID-design of Bootstrap. Float has issues with the vertical stacking, ...

Code snippet of how it's created right now:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" rowspan="2">module</td>
            <td>module</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">module</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>module</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Would you consider CSS grid? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: @ovokuro I'm open for all possible suggestions really. I'm looking into this right now. Thanks!

Comment: grid is indeed the way where elements can be spanning rows and columns. Do you have any HTML structure and CSS that shows what you have tried and from which one can advise you ? Mind http://caniuse.com/#search=grid  You will need to set the spanning values to each boxes : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dzPBXK  a tutorial : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ (almost complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Customize grid according to your needs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:black;">.col-sm-6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:green;">.col-sm-3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:blue;">.col-sm-3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">.col-sm-6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">.col-sm-3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:yellow;">.col-sm-3</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```